# How to get the key and value fr a JSONObject in java

Tags: java, json, algorithm, rest

We have a JSON request and I need to check some conditions.

1. by getting the value from a key.(eg. Getting Antony from the key Name)
2. checking whether the key is there in json object or not. (Check Dob key is there or not in the below object)

JSON request would be in the below format.

"School":{"RollNum":"123","Name":"Antony","Address":"India"}

Please someone help me with the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an attribute, use this:

```
String key = jsonObject.get("key").getAsString();
```

To check an attribute:

```
jsonObject.has(key) && !jsonObject.isNull(key);  //key will be your field to check
```

If you want to check if the string is not empty as well, use this:

```
jsonObject.has(key) && !jsonObject.isNull(key) && jsonObject.has(key) && !jsonObject.isNull(key);
```

Comment: I need to check the condition where key 'Dob' is present in the json object or not. If I do as above I will get the exception if I am not passing Dob key value pair in json request object

Comment: Did you use the jsonObject.has(key) ?? What exception are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this way.

```
JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) JsonParser.parseString("yourJason");
String name = jsonObject.get("Name").getAsString();
```

If your json have nexted object, than you can try.

```
JsonObject school = jsonObject.get("School");
String name = school.get("Name").getAsString();
```

Comment: What is "your Jason" passed in parseString??

Comment: Is it my json request object ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the library `Gson` to you.

For Maven:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
  <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.6</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Simple Example:

```java
Gson gson = new Gson();

JsonObject json = gson.fromJson("your json string", JsonObject.class);

// get attribute
String name = json.get("Name").getAsString();

// check an attribute
if(json.has("someKeyName")) {
  // do something else
}
```